# If an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues and $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors is it diagonlizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Is this always true? also if a matrix has less than $n$ eigenvalues but still $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors would it be diagonalizable in this case?

Comment: Yes. An $\;n\times n\;$ matrix is diagonalizable **iff** it has $\;n\;$ linearly independent eigenvectors. BTW, your question's title doesn't match the question

Comment: Eigenvalues are not linearly independent, maybe you mean eigenvectors.

Comment: @DHMO no I didn't. But i forgot eigenvalues -> eigenvectors. But that was intentional since it is important that the poster knew it.

Comment: This can clearly happen: the identity matrix is obviously diagonal(izable), and its only eigenvalue is $1$. The answer below shows that it holds in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $n$ eigenvalues be $\lambda_1$ through $\lambda_n$ and the eigenvectors be $\vec v_1$ through $\vec v_n$.

Then, we have:
$$A\begin{bmatrix}\vec v_1&\vec v_2&\cdots&\vec v_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\vec v_1&\lambda_2\vec v_2&\cdots&\lambda_n\vec v_n\end{bmatrix}$$

After, that:
$$A\begin{bmatrix}\vec v_1&\vec v_2&\cdots&\vec v_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\vec v_1&\vec v_2&\cdots&\vec v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&\lambda_2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $P=\begin{bmatrix}\vec v_1&\vec v_2&\cdots&\vec v_n\end{bmatrix}$ and $Q=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&\lambda_2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$.

We have $AP=PQ$.

Since the eigenvectors are linearly independent, $P$ is invertible.

Hence, $A=PQP^{-1}$, and we have proved that $A$ is diagonalizable, since $Q$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Equivalently, one has $A=\sum_k \lambda_k \vec{v}_k\vec{v}_k^T$ which is diagonal in the $\{\vec{v}_k\}$ basis.